# Custom Google+ Button on storyboard is not showing properly in iOS

Tags: ios, google-plus

I am create a UIButton for signin to google+ using Storyboard. But after using GPPSignInButton my custom button is hiiden by default button of google+.

First it showing a blue color like below.

[image]

After make it buttontype to custom its showing perfect but default google+ button not my button.

[image]

How can i solve this one? Please help me

Comment: show some code or google+ delegate code?

Comment: typedef enum {
  kGPPSignInButtonStyleStandard = 0,
  kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide = 1,
  kGPPSignInButtonStyleIconOnly = 2
} GPPSignInButtonStyle;
typedef enum {
  kGPPSignInButtonColorSchemeDark = 0,
  kGPPSignInButtonColorSchemeLight = 1
} GPPSignInButtonColorScheme;
@interface GPPSignInButton : UIButton
@property(nonatomic, assign) GPPSignInButtonStyle style;
@property(nonatomic, assign) GPPSignInButtonColorScheme colorScheme;

Comment: in my storyboard i change to buttontype custom after that its look like 2nd image

Comment: in their delegate method,they hide the gpssigninbutton once you press the login button

Comment: I can't get u. please clarify me

Answer (score 1):

Do not use GPPSignInButton, use UIButton. And use GPPSignIn in your button's method.

like this.

```
- (void)googlePlusLogin:(id)sender {
    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
}
```

You can use your custom button.

Comment: Can I see your code? I can't answer before know your code @jeekOnline

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actually I am able to fix this issue after adding constraint `Aspect Ratio` in Auto Layout of button and changing button type from `Custom` to `System`

Answer (score -2):

Just delete the button title and set background color to default.